# What are your thoughts on building multiple ionic Cordova apps from single codebase?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I can’t find a solution to this and wondering if anyone has one...

We’ve developed an app with all features, but we also need three more apps that do the same thing with specific features removed or added depending on which app it is; but essentially runs from the same code and just has a flag to tell the app which features to turn on and off... like mode = “a” or mode = “b”

When it come to building the ionic Cordova app we can change that flag to build the correct app but at the moment have to constantly switch the config.xml as each mode needs to build into a different app with different resources and id etc.

There doesn’t seem to be a cli option for Cordova to say “use this config.xml” for building, I’d have thought you’d be able to do something like:

Ionic Cordova build iOS —-xml=mode2.xml

But you can’t!

Is there a better way of doing this than constantly having to keep switching the xml file for each build ?

Comment: if there isn't a better way you could write a simple batch file / shell script to automate renaming the xml file